# Setting message size for spring sockjs websocket server

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs, spring-websocket

I have used spring sockjs server implementation for websockets. It supports messages upto 2kb but above that the websocket connection breaks -gives an 1006 error. If I reduce the message size, then it runs ok.
I went through the docs as well as classes, but could get a place where I can increase this limit. Have asked in spring forum as well but no reply.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved, the way spring document has mentioned, did not worked for me -tomcat would not pick the parameters from there. Finally getting hold of ServletServerContainerFactoryBean  (which is always singleton) and setting the properties there worked for me. Details:
[How to increase output buffer for spring sockjs websocket server implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730566/how-to-increase-output-buffer-for-spring-sockjs-websocket-server-implementation/21809239?noredirect=1#21809239).

Answer (score 0):

Any stack traces in the server logs? What server? And what transport is being used (websocket, xhr-streaming, other?) For the WebSocket transport you may be hitting default limits on the message buffer. Have you seen the section on [Configuring the WebSocket Engine](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-runtime-configuration) in the documentation?

Comment: I had asked a similar question got it resolved, The way its mentioned in document does not worked, see the link for how it got working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730566/how-to-increase-output-buffer-for-spring-sockjs-websocket-server-implementation/21809239?noredirect=1#21809239,