# Send a file using websocket javascript client

Tags: java, javascript, spring, websocket

I'm trying to send a file using websocket connection to my server: 
I've implemented the websocket server side using java Spring
the client side is in javaScript
for some reason each time i send a binary message from client side using "blob" or "arraybuffer. the server recognise the message as text message not as binary.
what am i missing here?

Client Side

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Chat</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <h2>File Upload</h2>
            Select file
        <input type="file" id="filename" />
        <br><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Connect" onclick="WebSocketTest()" />
        <br><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="sendFile()" />

    <script>
    "use strict"
    var ws;
    function WebSocketTest()
    {
      if ("WebSocket" in window)
      {
         console.log("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
         // Let us open a web socket
         ws = new WebSocket("ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/service/audioHandler");
         ws.onopen = function()
         {
            // Web Socket is connected, send data using send() 
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({userName:'xxxx',password:'sgdfgdfgdfgdfgdf'}));
            console.log("Message is sent...");
         };
         ws.onmessage = function (evt)
         {
            var received_msg = evt.data;
            console.log("Message is received...");
         };
         ws.onclose = function()
         {
            // websocket is closed.
            console.log("Connection is closed...");
         };
      }
      else
      {
         // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
         console.log("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
      }
    }

function sendFile() {
    var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
    ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
    //ws.send('filename:'+file.name);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var rawData = new ArrayBuffer();           
    console.log(file.name);
    reader.loadend = function() {
    }
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        rawData = e.target.result;
        ws.send(rawData);
        console.log("the File has been transferred.")
        //ws.send('end');
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server Side

```
public class WebSocketController extends BinaryWebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private CallScopeStore callScopeStore;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AudioHandler.class);
    private static final String STOP_MESSAGE = "stop";

    @Override
    protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) {
        try {
         //do something....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(final WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        try {
            //do something....
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to send `Blob`, now you send `ArrayBuffer`, and may be you need to override MIME type of request

Comment: i tried this method: function sendFileBlob() {
var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
ws.binaryType = "blob"; ws.send(file);}  And the connection was closed with this Error: CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=No async message support and buffer too small. Buffer size: [8,192], Message size: [7,816,684]]

Comment: it seems, i need to stream the file as chunks, do you know how to do that?

Comment: If you will create a live example, I will try

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730566/how-to-increase-output-buffer-for-spring-sockjs-websocket-server-implementation

Answer (score 6):

You have to send the file as a blob.

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/service/audioHandler");
ws.binaryData = "blob";
ws.send(message); // Blob object
```

Probably you can find an error as you mention: "CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=No async message support and buffer too small. Buffer size: [8,192], Message size: [7,816,684]]". That happens because your WebSocket Engine need to be configured to allow binary message with the size you want. For example, in your WebSocketConfig:

```
@Bean
public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
    ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
    container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(500000);
    container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(500000);
    return container;
}
```

As you can see, you can set the maximun size allowed for your text and binary messages, just specify a size bigger than 7,816,684 (the file you was trying to send). By default, your buffer size is [8,192] so if you send a file with a smaller size than your buffer size, there shouldn't be problems. For more information, you can check [websocket spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-runtime-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Bean
public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
    ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
    container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(500000);
    container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(500000);
    return container;
}
```

WebSocketMessageBroker invalid.  @robert08

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class MyWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }


    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration webSocketTransportRegistration) {
        webSocketTransportRegistration
                .setMessageSizeLimit(1024 * 1024)
                .setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024 );

    }


}
```